Geometric interpretation of the heat ball
I'm reading the section on the Heat equation in Evans' book and there is something I don't quite understand.
He defines the heat ball as
$$E(x, t, r) = \left\{(y, s) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R~\big|~s \le t,~ \Phi(t - s, x - y) \ge \frac{1}{r^n}\right\},$$
with $\Phi(t, x)$ being the heat kernel in dimension $n$, i.e.
$$\Phi(t, x) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}\right).$$
He gives an interpretation of this set, displayed on the figure below.

I am wondering how does he get the shape. It seems to be some kind of ellipsoid but I don't quite get it. I tried to get an intuition by shifting and rescaling to $E(0, 0, 1)$ and by fixing time, i.e. for some $s_0 \le 0$ and
$$E(0,0,1) \cap (\mathbb R^2 \times \{s_0\}) = \left\{y \in \mathbb R^2 ~\bigg|~ \frac{1}{(4\pi |s_0|)} \exp\left(-\frac{|y|^2}{4 s_0}\right) \ge 1\right\},$$
where I considered $n = 2$ for the sake of simplicity. According to the picture in Evans, this set should be some kind of ellipse (right?), but I don't see how one should get that. Any idea on how to interpret this set ?

It isn’t literal more of an intuition. Below is a plot in Desmos for $n=3$, $x=0$, $t=0$, $r=(0.01)^{-1/3}$. (The $x$-axis represents $\vert y\vert$ with $y\in \mathbb R^n$ and the $y$-axis is $s$). You can see it’s more of a squished ellipse. 
